# How to use get the data using lxml

Tags: python, scrape

I would like to scrape the file of a page:

```
<body class="body_class" style="background:#444;">
<div class="data" id="id">
<div id="images" style="cursor: auto;">
<img id="page-1" src="image1.jpg" data-index="1" style="" data-bd-imgshare binded="1">
<p class="img_info">(1/14)</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I would like to get the data `image1.jpg`.

I tried the code

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get(r'http://example.com')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
a = tree.xpath('//div[@id="images"]/src/text()')
```

It fails. How to get the data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the text "image1.jpg" as data ?
if so, then simply use this xpath `//div[@id="images"]//@src`.

and if you want the image downloaded using the address in the src you can use.

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.gunnerkrigg.com//comics/00000001.jpg", 
"00000001.jpg")
```

Comment: Still cannot get the data. I included more html code. How to modify the xpath?

Comment: use this line `a = tree.xpath('//div[@id="images"]//@src')` instead of this `a = tree.xpath('//div[@id="images"]/src/text()')`

Comment: I tried both. I got the same result, an empty list.

Comment: it is possible that you are not getting the image directly in the source. in short what you see in the inspect console is not necessarily what you are getting. so try to find this image tag in the source by pressing 'ctrl + U' on chrome. you ll get the raw source of the page. try finding the same image in that page.